# T-SQL Arithmetic overflow error converting GUID to any other data type

Tags: t-sql

I have a query where I'm trying to concatenate a GUID to a string. No matter what I do, or what I try to convert the GUID to, I get an arithmetic overflow error. Even this:

```
select CAST(NEWID() as nvarchar)
```

Returns:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar
```

All similar questions have been resolved by a CAST or CONVERT but this always returns an error. Same result for CHAR or VARCHAR. Is there a setting I have to change to make this work or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've fallen into the trap of not specifying a length for your nvarchar. What you want is:

```
select CAST(NEWID() as nvarchar(36))
```

[ GUIDs are rendered as 36 character strings ]

When length is unspecified, SQL Server uses a default length of 30 for varchar/nvarchar when used in CAST and CONVERT functions.

You should **ALWAYS** explicitly specify your string length.

Comment: This was very valuable info, thanks. I always assumed not specifying the length in a `CONVERT` or `CAST` would just mean 'use whichever length works'.